# Objective-C plugin and CoreML model failing after email or Box transfer

Tags: objective-c, xcode, machine-learning, coreml

I have an plugin written in Objective-C which incorporates a CoreML model. The plugin and ML model compile and run fine locally. If I email or transfer the plugin model and coreml model via Box, my plugin crashes and throws a damaged error. I can get the plugin to function by removing extended attributes in terminal: `xattr -cr me/myplugin.plugin` but the ML section of code still fails.

If I monitor in XCode, I notice the following when the coreml model fails:

```
[coreml] Input feature input_layer required but not passed to neural network.
[coreml] Failure verifying inputs.
```

Is there some signature or attached attribute that would lead to this issue when transferring via email/box?

Comment: Did you figure out what was wrong?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there some signature or attached attribute that would lead to this
> issue when transferring via email/box?

Since you have access to both versions of each file (before emailing / transferring via box, and the after transferring).

Go to both versions of each file and do the following:

```
ls -la
```

If it has extended attributes there will be an @ symbol. For example:

```
drwxr-xr-x@ 254 hoakley staff 8636 24 Jul 18:39 miscDocs
```

If the versions after transfer do not have an @ symbol, then they do not have extended attributes.

Then for each file (both versions) do:

```
xattr -l filepath
```

This will display the extended attributes of each file.
You should compare the attributes of both versions of each file and see the difference. This should answer your question. If there is no difference, then no extended attribute has been added or removed.

Read : https://eclecticlight.co/2017/08/14/show-me-your-metadata-extended-attributes-in-macos-sierra/

Comment: xattr -l definitely shows added attributes, but after xattr -cr the original and transferred model are identical. The transferred one still leads to a crash though while the original works fine... Is there something else I could be missing?

Comment: @user3470496 did you check that the values of the attributes are the same before doing -cr?

Comment: they're different before -cr, identical after

Comment: @user3470496 does the original have any extended attributes? If so, you should not remove them - just ensure that the values are same in both files.